# Merged mining pool compatible with RSK

Tags: json-rpc

I have installed ckpool compatible with RSK. But there is issue in connection with rsk node. This error is caused "Failed to get result in json response to mnr_getwork". I have inatalled BTC node and RSK node on local. I have installe rsk node using ubuntu package. Could you help me why this error is caused.

I tried to post request using command like this.
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"mnr_getWork","params":[],"id":1}' http://localhost:4444
But "Can not find mnr_getwork method" error is caused. How can I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: static const char *rsk_getwork_req = "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"mnr_getWork\", \"params\": [], \"id\": %d}\n";
This code is written by C++
When run this code, """ can not find mnr_getWork method """" error is caused.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that probably the `mnr_` family of methods is not enabled by default.
You can do that by adding it to the `node.conf` file:

```
rpc.modules = [
    {
        name: "eth",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "net",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "rpc",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "web3",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "evm",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "sco",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "txpool",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "personal",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "debug",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "rsk",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
    {
        name: "mnr",
        version: "1.0",
        enabled: "true",
    },
]
```